# Trying to compare my two hash values. Both in big integer form

Tags: java, cryptography

Am trying to compare two values, hcB has been hashed then exponentiation is done on the value, and hci is doing the inverse of exp value. then comparing. They should be equal but are not.

```
public class Hash 
{
    static MessageDigest sha1;
    private static final int unitLength = 160; // SHA-1 has 160-bit output.


    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {

        String s  = new String("hello");

        BigInteger b =new BigInteger(s.getBytes()); // Big integer conversion

        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");    
        sha1.reset();
        sha1.update(s.getBytes());
        byte[] hc = sha1.digest();  
        BigInteger hcB=new BigInteger(1,hc);    


        KeyGenerator keyRC=new KeyGenerator();  
        try {
            keyRC.initialize();//generating key 


           BigInteger HashClValueExp=hcB.modPow(keyRC.RC, keyRC.p);// exponentiate of hashed value
           System.out.println("HasheCldExp Value: "+HashClValueExp);

           //Inverse RC         
           BigInteger inv = keyRC.RC.modInverse(keyRC.q);
           System.out.println("Inverse RC: " + inv);

          // Hash value inverse computation 
           BigInteger hci = HashClValueExp.modPow(inv, keyRC.p);
           System.out.println("hci: " + hci); // prints in hex
           System.out.println("hcB: " + hcB);   
           System.out.println("Compare hci and hcB :" + hci.compareTo(hcB));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the keygenerator javax.crypto.KeyGenerator ? Could you include imports in the code ?

Comment: The `KeyGenerator` class is from the `javax.crypto` package? If not where is it from?

Comment: I am afraid it's comes from a non standard http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15612-s98/projects/NextGen/ssl/docs/java.security.KeyGenerator.html beacause it doesnot build with javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.

Comment: I have a keyGenerator class which works fine.

Comment: Static and non-static calls to the same method, uppercase variables, a `BigInteger` input for the constructor that could lead to a negative number, calling `MessageDigest.reset()` before it is ever used... You should really try and create better code. Unless you *like* bug fixing of course.

Answer (score 2):

Basically to invert a modular exponentiation in `N` you need to compute the inverse `mod phi(N)`. (not `mod N`).

`phi(N)` is the number of elements in `N` where `gcd(x, N) = 1` (in other words, they don't share any prime factors).
   Computing the value of this function is difficult if you don't know all prime-factors of `N` and it comes that 
   factoring `N` can also not be done (as far as we know) efficiently.
   This is in fact the property the security of the *RSA*-crypto-system relies on.

So to get your code to work properly, you need your key-generator to generate a very specific set of values (my example is showing what you need for an *RSA* encryption):

```
class RSAKey {
    private final BigInteger p, q, e; // p and q must be distinct primes

    public RSAKey(BigInteger p, BigInteger q, BigInteger e) {
        this.p = p; this.q = q; this.e = e;
    }

    public BigInteger getN() { return p.multiply(q) } // return N
    public BigInteger getE() { return e }; // return e
    public BigInteger getPhiN() { // return phi(N)
        return p.subtract(new BigInteger("1").multiply(q.subtract(new BigInteger("1")); // (p-1) * (q-1)
    }
}
```

Your key-generator just hast to generate two random primes `p` and `q` and a random value `e` and pass them to the above class.
   You code for the modular exponentiation followed by inversion then looks the following:

```
RSAKey key  = keyGen.generateKey();

/* 
 * compute the decryption exponent d as:
 * d = e^-1 mod phi(N)
 */
BigInteger d = key.getE().modInverse(key.getPhiN());

BigInteger c  = m.modPow(e, N); // encrypt message m to ciphertext c
BigInteger m1 = c.modPow(d, N); // decrypt ciphertext c to message m1

System.out.println(m.equals(m1)); // the messages should be equal now
```

**Note**: Implementing RSA by yourself should be for educational purposes only! If you want to use RSA-encryption for anything else,
             you should use the Java *Cipher*-class and the Java *KeyGenerator*!

Comment: So i did that, now am comparing hcB to hci  to validate that hcB^RC  mod p = tmp. However i keep getting 1 meaning 1 value is greater than the other. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you maybe provide some sample-values for RC and p? And also the output you get for each of the 3 different calculations? Would help a lot for finding your problem.

Comment: When testing it locally for the values `hcB = 13, RC = 17, p = 24` everything seems to work fine with the fix i proposed.

Comment: P: 962048877184989219065632949256427765571258946809560127394331
Q: 684575201413679
RC: 667816516356056
RS: 465493717128880846407334544966412278385924491547196949965723
HasheCldExp Value: 796649730970984766905375219886152560229247413010049869879962
Inv RC: 887297399842733152674062473286499226852448913345164168309756
Compare hci and hcB :1
hci: 766921961952798238196730174445131022978327388182454663092395
hcB: 65081222357661489438400404128591249433537383087

Comment: Thanks for the numbers. I think I know what is wrong now. What are you actually trying to achieve with the exponentiation? Do RSA on your own? Inverting modular exponentiation is only possible if the values p, q and RC statisfy certain properties. I'll edit my answer explaining these, but it would be good to know your goal beforehand, so I can focus in my explanation on that.

Comment: I have explained the requirements needed to successfully perform the inversion in my updated answer. I used the RSA-cryptosystem as an example to show how to correctly perform the exponentiation followed by inversion.

Comment: well i initially thought it was similar to RSA but it differs a little, am working on private set intersection. So what an Essentially trying to implement is this.

hci = H(ci);
ai = (hci)Rc

am trying to validate that 

a`= ai^1/rc mod p = hci